# Code count used Excel Rows but ignores hiddenrows

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA with Excel and I want to get the amount of used Rows in my excel sheet.

Currently I am having this Code:

```
Private Sub

LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
Msgbox LastRow

End Sub
```

My Problem is that sometimes the Last Rows are hidden(height = 0) but I want the Code to still count them.
How to do this?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Maybe in your situation you can apply: `Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you can try below code to find last row even if the row is hidden

```
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim LastCell As Range
Set WS = Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
With WS
    Set LastCell = .Columns(1).Find(what:="*", _
        after:=.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A"), _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        lookat:=xlPart, searchdirection:=xlPrevious)
End With
Debug.Print LastCell.row
```

Comment: works great thanks! :)

just one little mistake: its written Worksheets not Worksheet